# Generating the borel $\sigma$-algebra of $C[0,\infty)$ by the cylinder sets

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

This is related with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236489/generating-the-borel-sigma-algebra-on-c0-1/) post:

Set $M := \{f \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} \ |\  f \text{ continuous }\}$ with the metric of the convergence in compact sets given by 
$$d(f,g) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\left(\max_{x\in [0,n]} |f(x)-g(x)|\right)\wedge 1}{2^n}$$

Then the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B(M)$ is generated by the cylinder sets $C(A,t_1,\dots,t_n):=\{f\in M \colon (f(t_1),\dots,f(t_n)) \in A\}$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $A \in B(\mathbb{R}^n)$

I try to use the technique used in the post above but I could only prove that for $\varepsilon < 1$ $$B(f,\varepsilon) = \bigcup_{m\in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{t \in [0,n]\cap \mathbb{Q}} \pi_t^{-1}\left(\left( f(t) -\left(\frac{1-2^{-m}}{2}\right)\varepsilon \ , \ f(t) +\left(\frac{1-2^{-m}}{2}\right)\varepsilon\right)\right)$$

The $ \varepsilon <1 $ condition comes from the fact that if $g \in B(f,\varepsilon)$ then $\left(\max_{x\in [0,n]} |f(x)-g(x)|\right)\wedge 1 \leq \varepsilon$ and this implies
$\max_{x\in [0,n]} |f(x)-g(x)| < \varepsilon$ only if  $\epsilon < 1$.

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: the equation above is not true, I don't know how to extend the technique on the other post for this case.

Comment: Thanks, that is the last ingredient!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: M is a separable metric space, so any open set can be written as a countable union of open balls with radius smaller than 1.

To see this, pick a countable dense subset $\{f_n\}$ and consider the balls $B(f_n, 1/k)$, $k\ge 2$, all of which have radius less than 1. Suppose $U$ is any open set. For any $f \in U$ there is a ball $B(f, 1/k)$ contained in U. By density, choose an $f_n$ with $d(f, f_n) < 1/(2k)$. Then we have $f \in B(f_n, 1/(2k)) \subset B(f, 1/k) \subset U$. So U can be written as a union of balls $B(f_n, 1/k)$ of which there are countably many.

Comment: but why you can take the radius smaller than 1?

Comment: @user90803: See edit.