# In $C[0,\infty)$: write open ball as a countable intersection/union of the inverse image of finite dimensional projections

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

This question is closely related to [another question on this website](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455735/generating-the-borel-sigma-algebra-of-c0-infty-by-the-cylinder-sets).

We endow $C[0,\infty)$ with the metric $d$ given by
$$
d\left(f,g\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}\left(1 \wedge \max_{t\in[0,n]}\left|f(t)-g(t)\right|\right).
$$
and we would like to show that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{C[0,\infty)}$ on this space coincides with the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes all finite dimensional projections measurable.

I already showed that the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes all finite dimensional projections measurable is contained in $\mathcal{B}_{C[0,\infty)}$, but for the other inclusion, I have been grinding my gears, but I have not found a way to show it yet.

My reasoning is as follows: with this metric $d$, the space $C[0,\infty)$ is separable (let $\left\{f_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ be an enumeration of this dense subset) and second countable, where we may take as the countable base the open balls around the $f_k$ with rational coefficients that are smaller than $\tfrac14$.

This means that we can show that $\mathcal{B}_{C[0,\infty)}$ is contained the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes all finite dimensional projections measurable when we can show that such an open ball can be written as the countable union or intersection of the inverse image of some projections, as $\mathcal{B}_{C[0,\infty)}$ is generated by these open balls.

However, this is where I get stuck: given this metric, we know that two functions are close to each other, when they are close together early on, but they may differ hugely after a certain time. I find it difficult to turn this loose describtion of closeness with respect to this metric into something useful and I was wondering if some of you could help me out here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the equivalent metric $\sup\lbrace 1/n \wedge \max\limits_{t\in [0,n]} |f(t)-g(t)|: n\in \mathbb N\rbrace$.