# A question on the Borel sigma field on $C[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $C$ denote the σ-field on $C[0,1]$ generated by all open balls : the open $\epsilon$-ball around $f$ is the set $\{g ∈ C : ρ(f, g) < \epsilon\}$
>
> Denote $\forall t∈[0,1], π_t : C[0,1] →\Bbb R$ to be the evaluation map (also called the projection map), defined as $π_t(f)=f(t),t∈[0,1]$,
>
> (1) Show that $C$ is the σ-field generated by $\{π_t,t∈[0,1]\}$.
>
> (2) Show also that a map $φ:(Ω,A)→(C[0,1],C)$, where $(Ω,A)$ is any measurable space,is measurable if and only if $π_t◦φ$ is measurable for all $t∈[0, 1]$ .

My attempt :

(1) By showing that any closed ball is in $\{π_t,t∈[0,1]\}$ , I have been able to show $C \subseteq \sigma\{π_t,t∈[0,1]\}$. Was able to show the other way thanks to [Generating the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $C([0,1])$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236489/generating-the-borel-sigma-algebra-on-c0-1)

(2) Could do one way : if $\varphi$ is measurable then it's obvious but how to show the other way i.e. $π_t◦φ$ is measurable for all $t∈[0, 1] \implies \varphi$ is measurable .

> Note that the trick we normally use for doing such proofs for projections won't work, since $[0,1]$ is uncountable! Can I use $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$ somehow?

Thanks in Advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to show is that $E \in \sigma (\pi_t:0\leq t \leq 1\}$ implies $\phi ^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal A$. Since the collection of all sets $E$ in $C[0,1]$ such that $\phi ^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal A$ is a sigma algebra (by a simple verification) it is enough to consider the special case when $E=\{\omega: (\pi_{t_1} (\omega),\pi_{t_2} (\omega),\cdots,\pi_{t_n} (\omega)) \in A$ is in $\mathcal A$ for any Borel set $A$ in $\mathbb R^{n}$ (and $n,t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n)$ are arbitrary.  But $$\phi^{-1}(E) =(\phi\circ \pi_{t_1},\phi \circ\pi_{t_2},\cdots ,\phi \circ\pi_{t_n})^{-1}(A)$$ which belongs to $\mathcal A$ because $(\phi\circ \pi_{t_1},\phi \circ\pi_{t_2},\cdots ,\phi \circ\pi_{t_n})$ is a measurable map from $\Omega$ into $\mathbb R^{n}$.

Comment: Can you please explain this part in details : "it is enough to show consider the special case when $E=\{\omega: (\pi_{t_1} (\omega),\pi_{t_2} (\omega),\cdots,\pi_{t_n} (\omega)) \in A$ is in $\mathcal A$ for any Bore set $A$ in $\mathbb R^{n}$ (and any choice of $n,t_1,t_2,\cdots,c_n)$"

Comment: @Coherent The reason is sets of this type generate $\sigma (\pi_t:0\leq t\leq 1)$

Comment: So taking finitely many at a time will generate it? Can you give a proof?

Comment: If $(f_i)$ is a collection of real valued functions then $\sigma (f_i)$ is the sigma algebra generated by sets of the type $(f_{i_1},f_{i_2},...,f_{i_n})^{-1} (A)$ where $A$ is  Borel set in $\mathbb R^{n}$ and $i_k$'s belong to the index set. This follows by a straightforward verification.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand it now.

Comment: But can one just use the result that : if $S$ is a sigma field (on $\Omega$ ) generated by a family of functions $ \{f_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$  ( I is arbitrary!) then a function $h$ defined on $\Omega$ is measurable wrt $S$ iff it is measurable wrt the sigma field on $\Omega$ generated by any countable sub-family ?

Comment: @Coherent If you use countable subfamily of $(\pi_t)$ then you have to consider functions with values in $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ and you have to deal with Borel sigma algebra of this space. Isn't it better to consider functions with values in Euclidean spaces instead?